# better way to express a function in Go (Struct methods)

Tags: go, methods, struct

This is a function to traverse an array of Points. A Point is a struct with elements x and y of type int. The traverse function is called from another function with a value of dir. The if check at the beginning of the loop can be avoided because the dir value, once the function is called, does not change. Is there a better way to express this logic in Go? The struct method returns a Point. I have provided one example of the struct method.

```go
type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (p Point) next_row() Point {
    nearby := Point{p.x + 1, p.y}
    return nearby
}

func trv_point(p Point, p_list []Point, dir string) int {
    seg_count := 0
    var nearby Point
    for {
        if dir == "up" {
            nearby = p.prev_row()
        }
        if dir == "down" {
            nearby = p.next_row()
        }
        if dir == "left" {
            nearby = p.prev_col()
        }
        if dir == "right" {
            nearby = p.next_col()
        }

        if !check_point_in_slice(p_list, nearby) {
            break
        }
        seg_count++
        p = nearby

    }
    return seg_count
}
```

Comment: "Better" in what way? Performance of this code should be sufficient in all but the most extreme cases, and it seems perfectly readable. What about it are you trying to improve?

Comment: You could do a switch on dir. That would allow you to drop a few lines and expressions without making it more obscure.

Comment: if we call the function like p :=trv_point(p,arr,"up")
The if condition at the beginning of the for{} is not necessary because it is always going to evalutate to the same. I was looking at a way to initialize a partial function before the for{}.. Not sure if it is clear or even if that is possible

Comment: OP wants to know if we can "cache" the method function. I'd like to know that, too. Yes? No? How?  Would `fn := p.next_row()` be general enough to use with any given "p", or only the specific "p".  OP: we might have to make non-method functions and use them instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `dir` is not change here, those `if` statements are redundent, also you should use `if-else` statments for this case because just one of the ["up", "down", "left", "right"] could happened.
First look to this example:

```go
type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (p *Point) next_row() {
    p.x += 1
}

func main() {
    p := Point{0, 0}
    f := p.next_row

    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        fmt.Println(p)
        f()
    }
    fmt.Println(p)
}
```

the output will be:

```go
{0 0}
{1 0}
{2 0}
```

Here we change the receiver from `(p Point)` to `(p *Point)` because we want to save the effects on `x` and `y`.
By this assumption we could rewrite as:

```go
type Point struct {
    x int
    y int
}

func (p *Point) next_row() {
    p.x += 1
}

func get_move(dir string) func() {
    var f func()
    switch dir {
    case "up":
        f = p.prev_row
    case "down":
        f = p.next_row
    case "left":
        f = p.prev_col
    case "right":
        f = p.next_col
    }
    return f
}

func trv_point(p Point, p_list []Point, dir string) int {
    seg_count := 0
    var nearby Point
    f := get_move(dir)
    for check_point_in_slice(p_list, p) {
        f()
        seg_count++
    }
    return seg_count
}
```

Comment: This is nice! It is not doing exactly what the original code segment is doing(returning a new Point) nevertheless, it is a great workaround. I ll just hold on for 1-2 days before accepting the answer. Is that ok?

Comment: it is just a suggestion :)

Comment: some minor changes in the code, get_move(p *Point,dir string) and get f:= get_move(&p,dir). and trv_point should have one call of f() outside the loop